# Suggestions for icons for windows applications

Tags: gui-design, icons

I would appreciate if anybody could give me suggestion to create icons for Preview, Advisor, Settings, Reports, Report a Problem.

Please keep in mind all these icons are for a print application for windows.

I am specially a big fan of apple icons. They are really awesome.

Comment: This question is too much like "here is my work, please do it for me".  If you are stuck on a specific icon, then ask about that but also show what research you have done.

Comment: You're giving no context for your icons. We don't know type of application; the core types of information; the sizes required; whether they are standalone or with text; the colour schemes; nothing to relate noun or verb (object and action). No detail about what you've looked at but don't like. If this was a brief for a graphic designer, it simply wouldn't get looked at. Consequently this feels like the wrong place for this question, or the question needs to be better formed so that it can be answered more accurately and with a greater likelihood of relevance for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this website: http://www.iconfinder.com ?

It brings up a pretty good choice of possibilities, except for "Advisor". Can you explain what that means or what it does?

Comment: I checked on this site. I want something like apple icons. Need suggestions/ideas. Advisor is nothing but gives an option to switch from a selected option to another best available options.

Comment: I was trying to give you a starting point, something to put you on track. The site I recommended may not give you exactly what you want but should at least inspire you. What do you mean by "like apple icons"?

Comment: visit this link-http://www.apple.com/mac/app-store/ you can see some icons on apple site.

Comment: I use a Mac so I am quite aware of some "Apple" icons. I just don't know what *you* believe is typical about them.